# Find facts using multiple values

Tags: clips

```
   (defglobal ?*myGlobal* = 0)

    (deftemplate myTemp
        (slot one)
        (slot second)
        (slot third)
        (slot fourth)
```

)

```
 (find-fact ((?p myTemp)) (eq ?p:one aValue))
```

I want to match a fact based on multiple values; the code above matches facts using only one value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use boolean clauses:

```
(assert (myTemp (one asd) (second jhg))
        (myTemp (one asd) (second kjh))
        (myTemp (one bvc) (second jhg))
        (myTemp (one bvc) (second jhg) (third qwe)))

(find-fact ((?p myTemp)) (or (eq ?p:one bvc) (eq ?p:third qwe))
(<Fact-4>)

(find-fact ((?p myTemp)) (or (eq ?p:one bvc) (eq ?p:second jhg))
(<Fact-1>)

(find-all-fact ((?p myTemp)) (or (eq ?p:one bvc) (eq ?p:second jhg))
(<Fact-1> <Fact-3> <Fact-4>)
```